# How to define set of string in Delphi

Tags: delphi, set

how can i define a set of string and check if a user inserted string is in that set?
something like this:

```
type TDays = set of ('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun');

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var day :set of Tdays;
begin
day:=['Sat','Sun'];
if form1.Edit1.Text in day then
 showmessage('Holliday');
end;
```

Thanks

Comment: Use an enum rather than a string and it's gucci

Answer (score 4):

In Delphi, a [set](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets) cannot have `string` as its base type.

But instead, we can use an [enumerated type](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Enumerated_Types):

```pascal
type
  TDay = (dMonday, dTuesday, dWednesday, dThursday, dFriday, dSaturday, dSunday);
```

Then we can create a constant array indexed by `TDay` that contains the day names:

```pascal
const
  DayNames: array[TDay] of string =
    ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');
```

In modern versions of Delphi, we can use a record helper to facilitate translations between `TDay` values (used internally) and the `DayNames` strings (used for presentation and user input):

```pascal
type
  TDayHelper = record helper for TDay
    function ToString: string;
    class function FromString(const S: string): TDay; static;
  end;

implementation

{ TDayHelper }

class function TDayHelper.FromString(const S: string): TDay;
var
  d: TDay;
begin
  for d := Low(TDay) to High(TDay) do
    if SameText(S, d.ToString) then
      Exit(d);
  raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid day name: "%s"', [S]);
end;

function TDayHelper.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := DayNames[Self];
end;
```

Now we can do

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if TDay.FromString(Edit1.Text) in [dSaturday, dSunday] then
    ShowMessage('Weekend!');
end;
```

Of course, if you are using an old version of Delphi with no support for record helpers (≤ Delphi 2009), you can use ordinary functions instead.

---

Or, perhaps you are looking for a more lightweight approach (`uses StrUtils`)?

```pascal
const
  DayNames: array[0..6] of string =
    ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IndexText(Edit1.Text, DayNames) in [5..6] then
    ShowMessage('Weekend!')
end;
```

Needless to say, there are many variations on these themes, and several completely different approaches are possible as well.

Comment: Helped me a lot specially your last code. what i wrote in my question was an example. what i really wanted to know was is it possible to assign a string or better say "turn on" a string in a set or not. what i understood is "no". i can't directly use string in set and only ordinals are allowed. if  i am correct please tell me. thanks

Comment: @AmirTofighi: You are correct. The way sets are implemented in Pascal/Delphi makes it impossible to use strings as set members. You must use ordinals (and only small such ordinals).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't. But you can make it look as if you can.

Look at this function (which compiles)

```
function Test : boolean;
var
  iTest : TDays;
begin
  iTest := [ 'Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri' ];
  Result := 'Sat' in iTest;
end;
```

Here is the full unit - but note there is more than one way to achiev this - it is just an examples:

```
unit UnitTest;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TDay = (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun );

  TDays = Record
  private
    fValue : array[ TDay ] of boolean;
    class function Day( const pDay : string ) : TDay; static;
  public
    class operator implicit( a: array of string ) : TDays;
    class operator in( a: string; b: TDays ) : boolean;
  End;


implementation

{ TDays }

class function TDays.Day(const pDay: string) : TDay;
begin
  if SameText( pDay, 'mon') then
  begin
    Result := Mon;
  end
  else if SameText( pDay, 'tue') then
  begin
    Result := Tue;
  end
  else if SameText( pDay, 'wed') then
  begin
    Result := Wed;
  end
  else if SameText( pDay, 'thu') then
  begin
    Result := Thu;
  end
  else if SameText( pDay, 'fri') then
  begin
    Result := Fri;
  end
  else if SameText( pDay, 'sat') then
  begin
    Result := Sat;
  end
  else if SameText( pDay, 'sun') then
  begin
    Result := Sun;
  end
  else
  begin
    raise Exception.Create(pDay + ' is not a valid day');
  end;
end;

class operator TDays.implicit(a: array of string): TDays;
var
  i: Integer;
  j : TDay;
begin
  for j := Low( TDay ) to High(TDay) do
  begin
    Result.fValue[ j ] := FALSE;
  end;
  for i := 0 to Length( a ) - 1 do
  begin
    Result.fValue[ Day(a[ i ])] := TRUE;
  end;
end;


class operator TDays.in(a: string; b: TDays): boolean;
begin
  Result :=b. fValue[ Day( a ) ];
end;

function Test : boolean;
var
  iTest : TDays;
begin
  iTest := [ 'Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri' ];
  Result := 'Sat' in iTest;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Shouldn't `class operator TDays.implicit` start by filling the result with zeros?

Comment: Could do `FillChar(Result, SizeOf(Result), 0)`, but a loop is perfectly fine too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TObjectList or TObjectDictionnary too :

```
    uses
  System.SysUtils, Generics.Collections;

type
  TDay = (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun);

  TDayInfo = record
  public
    Day     : TDay;
    Holiday: boolean;

    constructor Create(aDay: TDay; aHoliday: boolean);
  end;

  TDayDictionnary = class(TObjectDictionary<string, TDayInfo>)
    constructor Create;
  end;

{ TDayInfo }

constructor TDayInfo.Create(aDay: TDay;aHoliday: boolean);
begin
  Day     := aDay;
  Holiday := aHoliday;
end;

{ TDayDictionnary }

constructor TDayDictionnary.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;

  Add('Mon', TDayInfo.Create(Mon, False));
  Add('Tue', TDayInfo.Create(Tue, False));
  Add('Wed', TDayInfo.Create(Wed, False));
  Add('Thu', TDayInfo.Create(Thu, False));
  Add('Fri', TDayInfo.Create(Fri, False));
  Add('Sat', TDayInfo.Create(Sat, True));
  Add('Sun', TDayInfo.Create(Sun, True));
end;

var
  d: TDayDictionnary;
  s: string;
begin
  try
    d := TDayDictionnary.Create;
    s := 'Sat';

    if d.ContainsKey(s) then
      Writeln(d.Items[s].Holiday);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(d);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: `d := TDayDictionnary.Create;` **must** be placed *before* the `try`. Otherwise, if an exception is raised in the constructor, you will do `d.Free` on a random pointer `d`. That's *very* bad. (I'm assuming `d`  is a local variable here. If not, it is safe, because then it is initialized to `nil`. But the idiom is to use the order I suggested in *every* case, even if it the alternative happens to be safe in some situation.)

Comment: You are right its a mistake when I remove the first try...finall of the new consol app I do as example :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's better you use a set without strings:

```
type
  TDay = (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun );
  TDays = set of TDay;
```

And use RTTI to convert automatically the values when you need it.
You can get the string using:

```
  sDay := 'Sat';                                      // string value
  day := TDay(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TDay), sDay));    // TDay value
```

And get the enum value using:

```
  day := Sun;
  sDay := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TDay), Ord(day));
```

You need to add the `System.TypInfo` to `uses`.